# What is the correlation of [1,2,3] and [1,5,7] to 8 decimal digits?

Tags: correlation

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949226/calculating-pearson-correlation-and-significance-in-python/7939259#7939259) describes computing a Pearson correlation of [1,2,3] and [1,5,7] in several different ways in Python. The most straightforward implementation from [the definition in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Definition) comes up with

```
0.973328526785
```

while Excel, R, NumPy, an online calculator, and a different Python implementation (involving what looks like a more numerically unstable calculation to me) come up with

```
0.981980506
```

I am just curious to know what you think.

Comment: The exact correlation is $\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{7}} = \sqrt{\frac{27}{28}} \approx$ 0.981 980 506 061 965 716.  The value you obtain for the Wikipedia definition looks like a mistake in your implementation: the discrepancy is far too large to be due to numerical instability.  (Besides, the Wikipedia formula is the more stable of the two algorithms!)  Your result is almost exactly $\sqrt{\frac{18}{19}}$.

Comment: I put a comment in the SO post: Beware of the type of the variables! You have encountered an int/float problem. In `sum(x) / len(x)` you divide ints, not floats. So `sum([1,5,7]) / len([1,5,7]) = 13 / 3 = 4`, according to integer division (whereas you want `13. / 3. = 4.33...`). To fix it rewrite this line as `float(sum(x)) / float(len(x))` (one float suffices, as Python converts it automatically).

Comment: Nice catch, @Piotr!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(originally written as a comment)

Beware of the type of the variables!

You have encountered an int/float problem. In `sum(x) / len(x)` you divide ints, not floats. So `sum([1,5,7]) / len([1,5,7]) = 13 / 3 = 4`, according to the integer division rules (whereas you want `13. / 3. = 4.33...`). To fix it rewrite this line as `float(sum(x)) / float(len(x))` (one float suffices, as Python converts it automatically).